# Pandas unstack() and pivot(): MemoryError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, out-of-memory

## Problem description

I'd like to unstack or pivot a DataFrame, but it raises the numpy exception `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.72 GiB for an array with shape (1844040704,) and data type bool`. I have tried this with a DataFrame with a numerical index `-> df.pivot()` and with a Multiindex `-> df.unstack()` ]. Both show the same exception and I don't know a way around. I don't feel like I have an exceptionally large dataset with 175199 rows. I have previously used unstack on DataFrames with more than 5mio rows. **The df will even become 2 x larger for the complete analysis!**

I try to unstack with `df_unstacked = df.unstack(level=0)`

## Additional info

Befor pivot / unstack, I had to add an unique index with `df['row_num'] = np.arange(len(df))`, because the dataset contains (wanted) duplicate index entries. Thats due to daylight saving time, where one day in octobre has 25 hours. The 2nd hour is duplicated.

I work with Jupyterlab from a virtualenv with python 3.7.

Package versions:

- pandas==1.1.2
- numpy==1.19.2
- jupyterlab==2.2.8

## Example data

```
                                    value
target_frame        row_num year         
2017-01-01 01:00:00 0       2016  10,3706
2017-01-01 01:15:00 1       2016  27,2456
2017-01-01 01:30:00 2       2016  20,4022
2017-01-01 01:45:00 3       2016  14,4911
2017-01-01 02:00:00 4       2016  14,2611
...                                   ...
2017-12-31 23:45:00 175195  2020  30,7177
2017-01-01 00:00:00 175196  2020  21,4708
2017-01-01 00:15:00 175197  2020  44,9192
2017-01-01 00:30:00 175198  2020  37,8560
2017-01-01 00:45:00 175199  2020  30,9901

[175200 rows x 1 columns]
```

## Desired result

The index will contain duplicates. For the record, i don't care if it's an index or a regular column.

```
                     value
year                 2016     2017  ...  2020
target_frame                  
2017-01-01 01:00:00  10,3706  11    ...  32
2017-01-01 01:15:00  27,2456  12    ...  32
2017-01-01 01:30:00  20,4022  13    ...  541
2017-01-01 01:45:00  14,4911  51    ...  123
2017-01-01 02:00:00  14,2611  56    ...  12
...                                   ...
2017-12-31 23:45:00  30,7177  12    ...  12
2017-01-01 00:00:00  21,4708  21    ...  12
2017-01-01 00:15:00  44,9192  21    ...  13
2017-01-01 00:30:00  37,8560  21    ...  11
2017-01-01 00:45:00  30,9901  12    ...  10

[35040 rows x 5 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

I will try to help you by addressing the issue of lack of memory, and a way to deal with it.

As your data already has almost 2 billion records, and the error is related to memory, I will focus on that without taking into account the transformations themselves.

If you are using something like, df, df_pivoted, df_unstacked, etc. With each transformation you are creating a new variable, and multiplying your memory consumption. So it is important to clear the memory in the process. Even if your data don´t seems big enough to consume all your memory.

One way to solve this problem is to work on "chuncks" and save each transformation step to a file in order to clear the memory.

So the first step is to save the files, with a simple 'dataframe.to_csv ()'.

The second step is to make the transformations using parts of the data that fit in memory.

For this, there is an argument in the pandas.read_csv () function, called 'chuncksize' that transforms your import object into iteration TextFileReader.

that way, if you want to access the data information, you need to iterate over it.

```
iterator = pandas.read_csv('file.csv', chuncksize=32)
iterator.shape # will raise an error.

AttributeError: 'TextFileReader' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

the right way to do it:

```
for chunck in iterator:
    print (chunck.shape)
```

output:

```
(32, ncols)
```

That way, to deal with your problem, you can work with chuncks and use the join functions to do the analysis as you need the data.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your effort. I am missing something, why does my data have 2 billion records? I have 175.200 rows. Maybe thats part of the problem? If i save my df to a pickle, it has ~5 MB


Edit: Ok, i see what you mean. The numpy error features 2 billion records. But why does it?

Comment: Right! I figured it was 175000 rows with multiple columns, and there was only one sample in the example. But if the data is really small, the problem must be in the functions that apply the reshape, they are not behaving as you expect and are formatting the data in a way that explodes the memory consumption.

Try to review how you are using the functions, if the parameters are well adjusted and also visualize the intermediate steps. If everything is fine, try to do the operation with little data so that even with the bug you can see what happened and understand what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a bug in pandas or numpy. There are differnet ErrorMessages with different pandas and numpy versions (Anaconda vs. pip). I coded the transformation myself and it runs in no time.

```
# Get the 2017 timestamp for the side_df
side_df = pd.DataFrame ({'timestamp': next_df.loc[next_df['year'] == 2017]['target_frame']})

for year in next_df['year'].unique():
    
    side_df[year] = next_df.loc[next_df['year'] == year]['value']

display(side_df)
```

Results in:

```
                timestamp     2016     2017     2018     2019     2020
8839  2017-01-01 01:00:00  10,3706   4,4184  14,7919  30,6942  31,0594
8840  2017-01-01 01:15:00  27,2456  23,7641  31,0019  40,2778  46,8350
8841  2017-01-01 01:30:00  20,4022  14,9732  23,8531  34,4941  41,3688
8842  2017-01-01 01:45:00  14,4911   9,4986  17,0181  28,8678  37,8213
8843  2017-01-01 02:00:00  14,2611   5,1241  14,0869  24,3203  34,4150
...                   ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...
43874 2017-12-31 23:45:00  10,9256  15,2959  22,6000  40,1677      NaN
43875 2017-01-01 00:00:00  10,9706   4,8184  11,5150  30,9208      NaN
43876 2017-01-01 00:15:00  35,6275  25,8251  30,2893  41,5722      NaN
43877 2017-01-01 00:30:00   24,555  17,7821  24,2928  35,5510      NaN
43878 2017-01-01 00:45:00     5,61  11,7059  20,0477  31,2884      NaN
```

There are still some problems in the dataset (like the NaNs), but that has nothing to do with this question.